# How to merge list of dicts with same key where values are the same?

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

Python newbe here. I have looked at Stack Overflow but cannot find a question exactly similar to this. I am trying to merge a list of dicts that have the same key and values are the same (so in my case merge where name is the same).

This is my current list:

```
current = [
    {'name' : 'food festival', 'category' : ['Miscellaneous', 'Undefined'], 'venue' : 'venue_1', 'price_1' : 100, 'price_2' : 120, 'start' : '2017-10-04T14:30:00Z'},
    {'name' : 'food festival', 'category' : ['Miscellaneous', 'Undefined'], 'venue' : 'venue_2', 'price_1' : 150, 'price_2' : 200, 'start' : '2017-11-04T14:30:00Z'},
    {'name' : 'music festival', 'category': ['music', 'pop'], 'venue' : 'venue_3', 'price_1' : 300, 'price_2' : 320, 'start' : '2017-12-04T14:30:00Z'}
    ]
```

And this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
final = [
  {
    'name': 'food festival',
    'category': ['Miscellaneous', 'Undefined'],
    'shows': [
      {
        'start': '2017-10-04T14:30:00Z',
        'venue': 'venue_1',
        'prices': [
          { 'price_1' : 100 },
          { 'price_2' : 120}
        ]
      },
      {
        'start': '2017-11-04T14:30:00Z',
        'venue': 'venue_2',
        'prices': [
          { 'price_1': 150 },
          { 'price_2' : 200 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'name': 'music festival',
    'category': ['music', 'pop'],
    'shows': [
      {
        'start': '2017-12-04T14:30:00Z',
        'venue': 'venue_3',
        'prices': [
          { 'price_1' : 300 },
          { 'price_2' : 320}
        ]
      }
   ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Your change to the "price" keys looks more complicated than just merging by key.. Are you sure you want "prices" to be a list of 1-length dicts?

Comment: Yes that would be the most desired result - maybe I should have been a bit more clear about this in the title and explanation.

Comment: I think like @IzaakvanDongen, why just don't use a list and the index is the of the price ? 
'prices' : [ 300, 320']

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp


current = [
    {'name' : 'food festival', 'category' : ['Miscellaneous', 'Undefined'], 'venue' : 'venue_1', 'price_1' : 100, 'price_2' : 120, 'start' : '2017-10-04T14:30:00Z'},
    {'name' : 'food festival', 'category' : ['Miscellaneous', 'Undefined'], 'venue' : 'venue_2', 'price_1' : 150, 'price_2' : 200, 'start' : '2017-11-04T14:30:00Z'},
    {'name' : 'music festival', 'category': ['music', 'pop'], 'venue' : 'venue_3', 'price_1' : 300, 'price_2' : 320, 'start' : '2017-12-04T14:30:00Z'}
]


SPECIAL_EVENT_KEYS = ("name", "category")
INVALID_INDEX = -1


def convert_event(event, special_event_keys=SPECIAL_EVENT_KEYS):
    ret = dict()
    prices_list = list()
    for key in event:
        if key in special_event_keys:
            continue
        elif key.startswith("price_"):
            prices_list.append({key: event[key]})
        else:
            ret[key] = event[key]
    ret["prices"] = prices_list
    return ret


def merge_events_data(events, special_event_keys=SPECIAL_EVENT_KEYS):
    ret = list()
    for event in events:
        existing_index = INVALID_INDEX
        for idx, obj in enumerate(ret):
            for key in special_event_keys:
                if obj[key] != event[key]:
                    break
            else:
                existing_index = idx
        if existing_index == INVALID_INDEX:
            new_object = dict()
            for key in special_event_keys:
                new_object[key] = event[key]
            new_object["shows"] = [convert_event(event, special_event_keys=special_event_keys)]
            ret.append(new_object)
        else:
            ret[existing_index]["shows"].append(convert_event(event, special_event_keys=special_event_keys))
    return ret;


def main():
    merged_events = merge_events_data(current)
    print("\nResulting object:\n")
    pp(merged_events)
    #print("Equal:", merged_events == final) # Commented out to avoid including the contents of 'final' in the answer as it would get too large; add it and decomment for testing purpose


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- The algorithm relies on the fact that if 2 (input) events have the same values for the keys: `name` and `category`, they will be merged together (via the `shows` list), otherwise they will be separate entries in the merged result
- `convert_event`: takes an *event* like it's in the initial list and converts it to an *event* for the output list:

  - Strips out the `name` and `category` keys
  - Aggregates `prices_*` entries in a dictionary as a list corresponding to the `prices` key
- `merge_events_data`: iterates on the initial event list and

  - If the *event* is not present in the output list (no entry with matching `name` and `category` values), it creates it
  - If such an *event* is found, its content (`shows`) is augmented with the current *event* data
- Code is *Python3* and *Python2* compatible
- It can definitely be improved from both style and performance *PoV*

Output:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q45794604>c:\Install\x64\Python\3.5.3\python.exe a.py
>
> Merged object:
>
> [{'category': ['Miscellaneous', 'Undefined'],
>   'name': 'food festival',
>   'shows': [{'prices': [{'price_2': 120}, {'price_1': 100}],
>              'start': '2017-10-04T14:30:00Z',
>              'venue': 'venue_1'},
>             {'prices': [{'price_2': 200}, {'price_1': 150}],
>              'start': '2017-11-04T14:30:00Z',
>              'venue': 'venue_2'}]},
>  {'category': ['music', 'pop'],
>   'name': 'music festival',
>   'shows': [{'prices': [{'price_2': 320}, {'price_1': 300}],
>              'start': '2017-12-04T14:30:00Z',
>              'venue': 'venue_3'}]}]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is a little confusing. I'll assume that the input, `current`, has to be fixed as it is, but I've changed `final` a bit to be more clear. I think `final` in this format will be more usable and more clear to interact with, although if you really want the other version of `final`, let me know.

```
import pprint

current = [
    {'name' : 'food festival', 'category' : ['Miscellaneous', 'Undefined'], 'venue' : 'venue_1', 'price_1' : 100, 'price_2' : 120, 'start' : '2017-10-04T14:30:00Z'},
    {'name' : 'food festival', 'category' : ['Miscellaneous', 'Undefined'], 'venue' : 'venue_2', 'price_1' : 150, 'price_2' : 200, 'start' : '2017-11-04T14:30:00Z'},
    {'name' : 'music festival', 'category': ['music', 'pop'], 'venue' : 'venue_3', 'price_1' : 300, 'price_2' : 320, 'start' : '2017-12-04T14:30:00Z'}
    ]

final = {}

for fest in current:
    name = fest["name"]
    if name not in final:
        final[name] = {"category": fest["category"],
                       "shows": []}

    show = {attr: fest[attr] for attr in ["start", "venue", "price_1", "price_2"]}

    final[name]["shows"].append(show)

pprint.pprint(final)
```

This has the output:

```
{'food festival': {'category': ['Miscellaneous', 'Undefined'],
                   'shows': [{'price_1': 100,
                              'price_2': 120,
                              'start': '2017-10-04T14:30:00Z',
                              'venue': 'venue_1'},
                             {'price_1': 150,
                              'price_2': 200,
                              'start': '2017-11-04T14:30:00Z',
                              'venue': 'venue_2'}]},
 'music festival': {'category': ['music', 'pop'],
                    'shows': [{'price_1': 300,
                               'price_2': 320,
                               'start': '2017-12-04T14:30:00Z',
                               'venue': 'venue_3'}]}}
```

Note: the dict comprehension I used may be specific to some version of Python3, I'm not sure. It can be easily replaced with

```
    show = dict((attr, fest[attr]) for attr in ["start", "venue", "price_1", "price_2"])
```

I've not changed much - mainly final is now a `dict`, where the name of the festival is a key to the dict representing it, and I've just kept `price_1` and `price_2` as keys, as there are only two fo them, which in my mind doesn't really justify a list of dictionaries.

Another suggestion: Rather than the string `"Undefined"`, you could use Python's `None` object.